# What is the term for the 'bastardisation' of common phrases and idioms?

Tags: phrases, idioms, terminology, lyrics, songs

Recently, I have been analysing lyrics to songs. Frequently, the writer inverts and 'bastardises' common phrases and idioms to play off of the established meaning.

I have been using the term 'bastardise' as a stand-in, as well as 'mincing' as they come close to what I am looking for.

However, I am not really familiar with grammatical techniques and would much prefer to have the correct terminology.

Some examples of this are :

> It takes a village to fake a whole culture

Which uses the proverb 'it takes a village (to raise a child)' and places culture in the place of a child, for negative effect.

> A participation trophy wife

Which takes 'participation trophy' and 'trophy wife' together.

> Like freaks of nurture

Which combines 'freaks of nature' with 'nature vs nurture'.

There are probably better examples but these are some I have seen recently, Will Wood, 'The Normal Album', (2020).

Additionally, if anyone knows the term for when a rhyming word is implied by the context of the sentence but omitted because the word is inappropriate, that would be helpful.

Some examples of this are :

> Come on, Dad
> Gimme the car
> Come on, Dad
> I ain't no runt
> Come on girl
> Gimme your, ....

Violent Femmes, 'Gimme the car' (1983), where the implied word is a slur for female genitalia.

> As when you cut a worm in half
> It still goes on without its head,
> I still go on without my heart,
> It's just I wish that we were,....

AlicebanD, 'Worms' (2011), where the implied word is 'Dead'.

Comment: One question per question, please. The latter question is already answered by [Is there a term for this word play where a song intentionally avoids completing a rhyme?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/168461/191178)

Comment: You might be thinking of [metalepsis](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/296107/142322), though the term doesn't carry derogative overtones by default.

Comment: _Bastardization_ is a judgemental term. How much politics do you want in your technical terminology?

Comment: I'd be happy to label them all *twists*. For example, *mansplaining* is a twist on overexplaining, and it's mansplaining to spell out the runt rhyme.

Comment: The Wikipedia page on [anti-proverbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-proverb) may be useful to you; it includes several categories of how such neologisms may be created. (See the picture of the guy in an "it takes a [village]" shirt.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do you call such sentences?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68056/what-do-you-call-such-sentences) ('People living in glass houses should use public restrooms.' etc /  [Is there a name for this type of sentence structure: "She looks as though she's been poured into her clothes, and forgot to say 'when'"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14949/is-there-a-name-for-this-type-of-sentence-structure-she-looks-as-though-shes) (Plus 'zeugmas'; there are at least 3 subsets here.)